# python3 numpy ndarray does not have consistant dimentions. Encountered odd behavor with shape atribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, shapes

I am using the numpy package in python 3. 
First, here is some code that shows the odd behavior I have encountered with the ndarray shape attribute.

```
threeDndarray = np.ndarray(shape=(2,5,2)) #3d ndarray to showcase behavor 
print(threeDndarray.shape)
**output:** (2, 5, 2)
print(threeDndarray[:][:][:].shape) 
**output:** (2, 5, 2)
#now the odd behavor
print(threeDndarray[:][1][:].shape) #expected (2,2) 
**output:** (5, 2) 
print(threeDndarray[:][:][1].shape)
**output:** (5, 2)
print(threeDndarray[1][:][:].shape)
**output:** (5, 2)
```

I believe this odd .shape behavior is related to the problem that I have. 
I want to store the values from five separate 2x2 matrices in a 3dndarray with the dimensions (2,5,2). I am unable to perform the operation my3dArray[:][i][:] = my2dMatrix, without getting an error related to dimension mismatching.

The specific error is

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (5,2)
```

I do not understand why I am getting this error or why the shape attribute has such strange behavior.

Comment: A stand alone `[:]` indexing does not make any changes.  Even when used on a Python list it just makes a copy of the whole list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using numpy indexing correctly.

```
array[1]
array[:][1]
array[:][:][1]
```

are all the same operation (a view into array, then access index 1 of the first dimension) because `(array[:] == array).all()` is `True`. I think you mean

```
threeDndarray[1, :, :].shape
threeDndarray[:, 1, :].shape
threeDndarray[:, :, 1].shape
```